# What to expect when changing URL to dev.azure.com format

Tags: azure-devops

I'm preparing to change our organization URL to the newer dev.azure.com format.  I've reviewed [this](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/organizations/accounts/rename-organization?view=azure-devops) and [this](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/help/2793597/things-to-do-before-and-after-you-rename-the-url-of-your-team-foundati), but neither really describe what I should expect or how to plan the transition with my developers.

Is it just a matter of pointing any local Git repos to the new origin URL?  I've also seen where local build agents may need to be updated.  Obviously favorites and such.

What am I missing?

Comment: Daniel - what you propose is in direct contradiction to link I've referenced, in which it states:
`Things to do after you rename the URL of your account:

We will not set up a redirect from your old account URL to the new URL. This  means that the old URL will 404, and you will have to update existing connection strings to point to the new URL. Additionally, you may have to take one or more of the following actions, depending on your specific configuration and how you use the service...
`